# How can I avoid using this.props to get components from another class? (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

So I figured that my list isn't updating after adding new content to it, it is just overwriting the list and then starting to merge items from there (all the previously added data in previous sessions disappear after the first add in the current session). I want the old data to stay but I am suspecting this.props (in HTMLList class) to be the problem.

Here's my code:

```
class HTML extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      html: [],
      description: "",
      body: ""
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    db.onceGetHTML().then(snapshot =>
      this.setState(() => ({ html: snapshot.val() }))
    );
    }

  addContent(description, body) {
    this.setState({
      html: [
        ...this.state.html,
        {
          description: this.state.description,
          body: this.state.body
        }
      ] 
    });
        addAnHTML(this.state.description,this.state.body);
  }

  updateByPropertyName(property, e) {
    this.setState({
      [property]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { html } = this.state;
    const { description } = this.state;
    const { body } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>The Home Page is accessible by every signed in user.</p>
        <input
          value={description}
          onChange={this.updateByPropertyName.bind(this, "description")}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Description..."
        />
        <input
          value={body}
          onChange={this.updateByPropertyName.bind(this, "body")}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Body..."
        />
        <button onClick={this.addContent.bind(this)}>Add Content</button>
        {!!html && <HTMLList html={html} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

    /...../

class HTMLList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: '',
      BODY: '',
      desc: '',
      html: ''
    };
  }    
  render() {
    const { html } = this.props;
    const { desc } = this.state;
    const { BODY } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>

        <h2>List of HTML available:</h2>
        {Object.keys(html).map((key, index) =>

          <div key={index}>
            {index + 1}.
            {html[key].description}

            /....../

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: (FIREBASE) here's my getHTMLOnce() function:

```
   export const onceGetHTML = () =>
    db.ref('Content').once('value');
```

Comment: `(key, index)` this isn't a good thing to use for assigning an array key, `key={index}` there are quite a few articles on why choosing a good key is needed.

Comment: `overwriting the list`, `I want the old data`... do you not see the problem in your own wording? If you want the old data to stay, stop overwriting it...? If you have data that you want to add to, you need to manage that in the state of a over arching component. When you get new `html` you then add that to your list and push it down to the `HTML` component via props

Comment: Why do you think I asked then? I have something wrong and I can't figure out how to solve it. @Callum Linington

Comment: You're missing the point, you've answered your own question...

Comment: Where is the overwrite happening? I fail to figure out where. @CallumLinington